# Como Utilizar flecha atrás en clase Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

¿Cómo puedo utilizar la flecha atrás que se muestra en el `Toolbar`? Tengo creado un menú horizontal con un `Toolbar` y un `TabLayout` utilizando la Clase Fragments, con el siguiente código.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 1", R.drawable.home_icon,true);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.chuletas_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.rcf_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.nar_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.estacion1_icon);

        horizontal_menu.showItems();

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }

        });


        horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });

    }

    private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Menu_1();
                case 1:
                    return new Menu_2();
                case 2:
                    return new Menu_3();
                case 3:
                    return new Menu_4();
                case 4:
                    return new Menu_5();
                default:
                    return new Menu_1();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Lo puedes indicar en el AndroidManifest.xml, poniendo la `Activity` en cuestión de este modo: **`<activity
            android:name=".ActivityConLaFlecha"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_laquesea"
            android:parentActivityName=".ActivityALaQueQuieresVolver"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.tupaquete.ActivityALaQueQuieresVolver" />
        </activity>`**

Comment: Hola A. Cenado, eso ya lo tengo puesto y no funciona, cuando pulso la flacha atras la aplicacion se cierra. He puesto el codigo para que lo veas en el primer post, lo que pasa que he reportado el primer mensaje para ver si lo pueden arreglar porque sale la informacion mal y no sale con los apartado que quiero, a ver si lo arreglan y se puede ver mas claro, y por cierto, no quiero volverponer a que actividad o fragmen volver, quiero que vuelva a la activiada anterior que estaba, y si vuelvo a pulsar la flecha que vuelva un atras un paso mas

Comment: El código se mostraba con dificultad, porque usaste una combinación de las etiquetas `<pre>` y `<code>`... Para futuras preguntas, en Stackoverflow es muy fácil poner el código. Tienes dos maneras posibles: 1. Antes de pegar el código, asegúrate de que **cada línea** del bloque de código tiene al menos 4 espacios en blanco a la izquierda (si al menos una línea no lo tiene el formato se romperá; o bien, 2. Puedes copiar todo el código en la pregunta, luego seleccionarlo todo y una vez seleccionado pulsar en el símbolo **`{ }`** que se muestra en el panel superior.

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta, ¿tú quieres que el `Fragment` actual se destruya cuando se presiona sobre la flecha de ir hacia atrás?

Comment: Gracias por lo de como editar los mensajes, sobre lo que me preguntas te voy a decirte que no se destruya, pensando en lo siguiente... si tengo que volver a ese Menu_1 me interesa que siga como lo deje, te digo esto porque va a mostrar contenido html, así cuando me pase al Menu_2 y vuelva al Menu_1 que muestre lo que tenia, poruque la paginas tenen enlaces que llevan a otra partes de ese mismo menu, o bien a otros menus (Menu_3, Menu_5).

Comment: @SoCu no podemos hacer nada para ampliar el espacio disponible para preguntas. Si necesitas más espacio, deberías plantearte que o bien esta pregunta es demasiado amplia o se está agregando demasiado código que realmente es innecesario para resolver el problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, yo creo que la pregunta no es tan extensa, solo ocupa dos líneas, el problema viene cuando me dicen que tengo que poner el código para que se vea lo que estoy haciendo, pero bueno... luego lo amplio como en otros casos que dicen que no se entiende, y porque no quiero extenderme mucho, y lo amplio incluso gráficamente y después ahí se quedan sin responder, cuando pase un tiempo volveré a preguntar si es que se sigue sin entender, lo que no me gusta, pero esto ya es cosa personal, es el espacio utilizado para responder, que no puedes poner una línea, tiene que ser todos seguido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entiendo tu pregunta y aqui esta la respuesta. El boton de atras tiene por defecto un comportamiento en el cual, regresa dentro del stack de activities hasta que sale de la app. Si lo que deseas es cambiar de fragment al darle click al boton de atras lo que tienes que hacer es sobre escribir el metodo onBackPressed() y validar la posicion actual de el pager. Seria de la siguiente manera.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;
    int currentPosition = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 1", R.drawable.home_icon,true);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.chuletas_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.rcf_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.nar_icon);
        horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.estacion1_icon);

        horizontal_menu.showItems();

        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
                currentPosition = position
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }

        });
```

Después de efectuar los cambios arriba, procede a sobreescribir el método onBackPressed()

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (currentPosition > 0){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition - 1);
        }

        else {
            finish(); // finaliza el acitivity actual 
        }
    }
```

Por ultimo cambia el evento del boton home, para que tenga el mismo comportamiento que el boton back fisico de tu dispositivo para centralizar ambos comportamientos.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Así cambias de fragment y cuando el viewpager este en pos = 0 seguirá con su comportamiento normal. Estaré atento por si esta solución no es suficiente

Comment: Perdona por no responder antes Jhon estuve entrando varias veces a ver si el amigo A. Cedano respondía a la pregunta que me hizo con mi respuesta y pensé que estaría ocupado con otros temas y lo deje para hoy, espero Jhon que por el tiempo que ha pasado no te sentase mal estar esperando mi respuesta, una pregunto tonta, como sobrescribo el método **onBackPressed()** me está dando error, otra cosa, `currentPosition = position;` termina en punto y coma, no? Mira esta captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2BqKq.png

Comment: Por cierto, hay gente que se dedica a dar puntos negativos, he visto que en tu respuesta tenías uno, no es la primera vez que veo esto, quiero que sepas que yo no he sido, yo te lo he quitado, pero no me deja darte un punto positivo.

Comment: En el caso de ser este el código correcto (mira la captura que aquí no se puede poner bien el código) http://funkyimg.com/i/2BqKq.png no funciona bien, sí que vuelve atrás, pero vuelve en la posición del menú, si estas en Menu_3, al pulsar pasas al Menu_2 y luego al Menu_1, pero con el botón físico del móvil, con la flecha del menú no, si se pulsa esta flecha la aplicación se cierra, y luego otra cosas, si vuelves al Menu_3, es menú no muestra la información que tenía antes de pulsar la flecha fisica del movil para ir atras.

Comment: Hola amigo, no te preocupes yo solo quiero ayudar jajaja. En efecto, me equivoque, no es position sino currentPosition apuntado a la variable global que guarda la posicion actual del pager. Y por lo otro, olvide mencionarte que debes apuntar el boton del toolbar tambien al evento onBackPressed para centralizar todo. Ya edito mi respuesta

Comment: Con respecto al problema del fragment 3 tenemos que ver un poco el comportamiento del FragmentPagerAdapter. Este adapter se ecarga de inflar y borrar los fragments segun una logica y es que este va a renderizar los fragments en las posicion n + 1 y n -1 siendo n la posicion actual del pager. Esto con el fin de mejorar el uso de memoria. Es decir que cuando regresar al fragment 1, el 3 se borra. Para mejorar este comportamiento como esperas se necesita una logica adicional la cual deberia ir en otra pregunta. Espero haberte ayudado y seguire al pendiente.

Comment: Hola, crear otra pregunta me parece bien para no mezclar temas diferentes, pero sería preguntar por los ciclos de vida de los Fragment, no? 
Sobre código que has puesto me estoy liando a incorporarlo el menú que he creado, el menú de los tres puntos del lado izquierdo, he puesto esta modificación al final del primer mensaje, si puedes revisarlo te lo agradecería, estoy intentando ponerlo en ese menú que también le he puesto el `onBackPressed()` y no me está funcionando.

Comment: Menos mal que saque una copia del proyecto porque he liado tanto el código que he tenido que empezar de nuevo, jeje, y he aprovechado para probarlo antes de poner el menú de los tres puntos, y he visto que el botón atrás no termina de funcionar bien, por ejemplo si estoy en el Menu 5, luego me paso al Menu 3, si pulso la flecha atrás no vuelve al Menu 5 que es lo que intento, si no que va al Menu 2, luego al Menu 1, y luego se sale.

Comment: La logica que te mostre debes combinarla con la logica que tu ya traes. Pon un punto de debugger y revisa si la asignacion de curentPosition esta bien. el metodo onBackPressed tambien debes combinarlo segun la logica que desees, no te lies tranquilo, todo esto es parte del aprendizaje pero te puedo asegurar que la logica que te menciono arriba funciona

Comment: Ok voy a intentarlo, gracias, ya he creado esa nueva pregunta sobre lo de grabar la información de los Fragment para que los siga conservando, y he puesto el mismo código que hay aquí, [¿Cómo se guardar los ciclos de vida de los Fragments?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132496/c%c3%b3mo-se-guardar-los-ciclos-de-vida-de-los-fragments)

Comment: Mucha suerte amigo y no te rindas que al comienzo este tipo de detallitos son un poco molestos de aprender al comienzo :D